# How to find a whole word in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to search a whole word in paragraph and word may end with special character.
For example text to be searched is `"search:"` and the paragraph is `"search: no search result found".` In this search result start index would be 0 and end index would be 6.

Regular expression i am using is `"\\bsarch:\\b"` however this regular expression escape special character `':'` .

Please help me to match whole word in java using Regex.
following is my java code

```
String textToBeSearch="search:";
        String regex = "\\b";
        String completeString="search: here is the string";
        String string = regex+Pattern.quote(textToBeSearch)+regex;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(string);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(completeString);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("found");
        }

        System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: can you not just escape the `:` as in "\bsearch\:\b"

Comment: `:` isn't a special character in regular expressions to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to find what the user entered and want to make sure that it won't match part of a word?

In that case, stay far away from `\b` and its cousin `\w`, as those are utterly useless for anything you would consider a word (it's a rough approximation what some programming languages thing as identifiers, nothing more). Best spell out explicitly what you want:

```
(?<=^|\s)search:(?=\s|$)
```

which means that preceding and following your search term is either whitespace or the beginning/end of the string. You may want to alter the lookahead to something like

```
(?=[\s.,:;'"!?)]|$)
```

maybe to allow for punctuation (and likewise, at least the opening parenthesis, in the lookbehind).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a "dynamic" regex based on a variable string, you need to *escape* that string by calling `Pattern.quote(String s)`.  For example, calling `Pattern.quote("[test]")` will return the regex:

`\[test\]` or more specifically it will return the string `\\[test\\]`

...which can be used as the regex to search with.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you could use following regex pattern:

**PATTERN**

```
\b(\w+?)[\:\?\!]?\b
```

Note: You can put as many **special characters** in the square bracekts as you want to include them in the search.

Some compilers have poor \b implementation and interpret `:` as new word so you would have to use following pattern:

**PATTERN 2**

```
\b(\w+?)[\?\!]?\b:?
```

or if you find it better:

```
\b(\w+?)\b[:\?\!]?
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
      String pattern ="\\b(\\w+?)[:\\?\\!]?\\b";

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);

      while(m.find())
      {
          //your code
      }
```

Note: I do not have the IDE here for java so I'm not 100% sure the code is **ALL** good but it should (pattern is fine however).